# how to style dynamically assign background to p-card of primeng?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, primeng, styling

I have to assign background to p-card (of primeng) depending upon the status. Example: red if status is failed, yellow for warning and green for success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way i have figured is using style property. The style property of p-card expects an object. So if we manipulate that object, we can change the bg color.

```
<p-card header="Simple Card" [style]="styleOBJ">
    some text
</p-card>

// in .ts file
styleOBJ = {'background':'lightblue'}
if(status == 'success') {
    styleOBJ = {'background':'green'}
} else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all disable  Disable view encapsulation in your component, and then add the styles,

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 templateUrl: './app/components/my.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app/components/my.css'],
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And than add some getter for ngClass to yours p-card