# How to change the background of PrimeNG's p-card component after ngAfterViewInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, background-color, styling

I would like to update the background of a p-card (PrimeNG component) AFTER initializing the view.

My real need:
I have an image in a p-card, I would like to retrieve the dominant color of an image and set it as the background color of the p-card component

.html side:

```
<p-card [style]="{'background': dominantColor}">
  <img src="path_to/image.png" #image />
</p-card>
```

.ts side:

```
  @ViewChild('image') imageElement: ElementRef | undefined;
  dominantColor: string = '#000000';

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const img = this.imageElement!.nativeElement;

    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx!.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      const imageData = ctx!.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      const data = imageData.data;

      let red = 0;
      let green = 0;
      let blue = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        red += data[i];
        green += data[i + 1];
        blue += data[i + 2];
      }

      red = Math.round(red / (data.length / 4));
      green = Math.round(green / (data.length / 4));
      blue = Math.round(blue / (data.length / 4));

      this.dominantColor = this.rgbToHex(red, green, blue);
    };
  }

  rgbToHex(r: number, g: number, b: number): string {
    return '#' + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
  }
```

Unfortunately, only the default value is taken into account and not the new value obtained...

I have already seen this topic:
[how to style dynamically assign background to p-card of primeng?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558954/how-to-style-dynamically-assign-background-to-p-card-of-primeng)
and tried the solution but without success, and as my need is a bit specific I took the liberty of creating this question
Thank you in advance for your help

---

Update:
Trying @Ricudo solution, didn't solved yet:
Html code:

```
<p-card [style]="cardStyle">
  <img src="assets/img/default/recipe-image.png" #image />
</p-card>
```

Ts code:

```
cardStyle = { background: '#000000' };

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const img = this.imageElement!.nativeElement;

    img.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx!.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

      const imageData = ctx!.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      const data = imageData.data;

      let red = 0;
      let green = 0;
      let blue = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        red += data[i];
        green += data[i + 1];
        blue += data[i + 2];
      }

      red = Math.round(red / (data.length / 4));
      green = Math.round(green / (data.length / 4));
      blue = Math.round(blue / (data.length / 4));

      this.cardStyle = { background: this.rgbToHex(red, green, blue) };
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see you pass an object as style to primeNg. It is right option because primeNG expects object. The problem is with change detection. You change the property of the passed object, but not the object itself, so change detection is not triggered and color is not changed. Just change `dominantColor: string = '#000000';` to `cardStyle = {dominantColor: '#000000'};` and then instead on `this.dominantColor = this.rgbToHex(red, green, blue);` use `this.cardStyle = {dominantColor: this.rgbToHex(red, green, blue)};`. And of .html substitute `[style]="{'background': dominantColor}"` with `[style]="cardStyle"`. Now the problem might be solved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it was not enough to solve my problem

I edited the question description to show you the code with your changes applied, I may have missed something again...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about your change detection strategy? if it is `OnPush` you need manually trigger it. Inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `.detectChanges()` at the end of `.onload`

Comment: I didn't know about strategy detection
From what I understand, according to the repo the p-card component does use OnPush (doc: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/card/card .ts)
It doesn't seem to work though, I did a stackblitz with your solution to show the problem that persists:
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/BenoitPE/primeng-card-demo-ja3msf

Comment: I mean your component. Simply try to add to your component constructor: `private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` and then after the line `this.cardStyle = { background: this.rgbToHex(red, green, blue) };` write `this._cdr.detectChanges()`

Comment: That's what I did but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem...
You can check it on stackblitz

Comment: Yeah, I've tried some things in your stackblitz and it looks like the issue is with component itself.  I've tried it on click event end everything works well, and timeout also doesn't help. So as a solution I can propose to make the background color transparent by default, wrap that p-card in your own div and make its background color dynamic

Comment: Ok, thank you for the time given and for the solutions you proposed.
For any other users who encounter the same problem,
I created an Issue on the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/15013

Comment: Also you know, I think it is not the best approach here to use `ViewChild` and `AfterViewInit`. `<img src="path_to/image.png" #image (onload)=yourCustomFunction(image)/>` would be better. I think it won't affect the problem but be more clear and readable.